# get number subscribe channel in search youtube api 3

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-channels

i can get number subscribe channel but by difficult method
and i don't if this method is right.

first i send GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=socre&type=channel&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

then i make for loop to get number subscribe for every channel after get channel id

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=UCblf4qm9ZhXD7sS_rZLTIOQ&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

then i get subscribe number for my result channels.

is it right method ? or there are easy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is the right way, except that you should use a channel-id list in the second request (a comma delimited list of channel-id's). Max 50 id's per request. And check that your connection allows long url's.